# Property value is not correct in event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, properties, viewstate

Im trying to set a value in a method as shown below but when i run btnSaveValue there is no value to retrieve. Ive even tried creating a private int val in the defaul class and assigning the value to that but still a blank value comes through - can anyone help me out?

thanks

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    valueAllocation valAlloc = new valueAllocation();

    public void declaringValue()
    {
        valAlloc.setValue(5);
        int testAlloc = valAlloc.getValue();
        lblResult.Text="Value set here is:"+testAlloc;  //THIS WORKS!!!
    }
    protected void btnSaveValue_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Value now is:" + valAlloc.getValue();   //DOESNT WORK??????!!!!!
    }
}

public class valueAllocation
{
    private int val;

    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        val = value;
    }
    public string getValue()
    {
        return val;
    }

}
```

Comment: when you say 'doesn't work', do you mean 'returns 0'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you need to save the value in each post using for example the `ViewState`.

This is a basic problem related with the ASP.Net page life-cycle.

Basically, every time you request your page, **a new instance of the page is created on every post**, and destroyed when the response returns to the client

If you want to keep the state across post backs, you need to manually save each value in the `ViewState`

### storing the whole type in the ViewState

I think this is your best bet

#### Custom Type

```
[Serializable]
public class valueAllocation
{
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

#### Code behind

```
protected valueAllocation MyObject
{
   get
   {
      if(this.ViewState["c"] != null) 
           return (valueAllocation)this.ViewState["c"];

      return null;
  }
  set
  {
      this.ViewState["c"] = value;
  }

public valueAllocation declaringValue()
{
    if (this.MyObject == null)
        this.MyObject = new valueAllocation { MyValue = 5 };

    lblResult.Text="Value set here is:"+ this.MyObject.MyValue.ToString();
    return this.MyObject;
}

protected void btnSaveValue_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    declaringValue()
    lblResult.Text = "Value now is:" + declaringValue().MyValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: looks like this is the right area, just having issues implementing it, i tried literally lifting what you have given me here and tried using this to get past compile errors (protected virtual StateBag ViewState { get; }) but it still wont compile.

Comment: What's the line it's throwing that error on? This approach is a canonical example of storage of view state in ViewState... (Dig into the ViewState documentation on MSDN for more examples.... I suspect your code is attempting to set ViewState to something rather than set values within it...)

Comment: Ok my bad, that's how I typically implement properties (when I develop server controls and I thought the basic idea was enough), the `this.ViewState` is meant to be used within the ASPX code behind. Check my updates answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you never called decalringValue(), do this

```
 public valueAllocation declaringValue()
    {
        valAlloc.setValue(5);
        int testAlloc = valAlloc.getValue();
        lblResult.Text="Value set here is:"+testAlloc;  //THIS WORKS!!!
        return valAlloc;
    }

protected void btnSaveValue_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        declaringValue()
        lblResult.Text = "Value now is:" + declaringValue().getValue();   //DOESNT WORK??????!!!!!
    }
```

Comment: sorry i call this in another method.

Comment: Can you post that part and when is that method called?

Comment: too much code to post, basically it queries a DB and if all is well, a value is passed to declaringValue above which should set the value. Then i want to use the value when the user clicks on the button. By this stage the value is blank. It does seem to be along the lines of ViewState but im having issues implementing it :(

Comment: Is that method called on pageload, or somewhere in the page lifecycle when your button is clicked?

Comment: in standard page lifecycle and called when i click the button yeah tahst correct

Answer (score 1):

It is because this is web application not a desktop.You have to manage the state of page.Because on web each request is new to server.

for your scenario you have to use "viewstate" technique for maintain the state of your page.

or you have to make your variable static if you want that value is not lose.

for further details googled `"State management in asp.net"`

Comment: What's with the suggestions to make the value static? That way lies nasty undefined behaviors when the postback comes after the appdomain is recycled...

Comment: yes off course all state and static variables also recycle with the appdomain recycled

Comment: ViewState survives AppDomains since it's pushed to the client. This can be useful or disastrous depending on your architecture...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like values were not set using valAlloc.setValue(SomeNumber); before calling the below method

Or I would say that valAlloc.val is having a default value of zero

```
protected void btnSaveValue_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Text = "Value now is:" + valAlloc.getValue();   //DOESNT WORK??????!!!!!
    }

so you lblResult.Text is getting a zero from  valAlloc.getValue()
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are looking for a static object and static linkage defined. If a global static object works for you in this case, please vote my reply up.